# Customize Bootstrap Form In Rails View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't figure out the proper formatting to modify my form partial in my view to look like the bootstrap form below with a appended button like this;

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

I would like the form to post to :home and the appended button to replace the default f.submit button in a Scaffold. Here's a Scaffold form partial that I'd like to modify.

```
    <%= form_for @anesu, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :home, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :home, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                anesus_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Please guide me on how to format my code and the right methods to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= form_for @anesu do |f| %>    
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <%= f.text_field :home, :class => 'form-control' %>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <%= f.submit "Go!", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```